# plesk disable sorting for particular column

Tags: php, zend-framework, plesk

I'm trying to develop new extension on plesk server (ver 11). I'm trying to create simple list with few columns. In the examples I found following code to create it through plesk (zend) mechanizm:

```
private function _getListRandom()
{
    $data = array();
    $iconPath = pm_Context::getBaseUrl() . 'images/icon_16.gif';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 150; $i++) {
        $data[] = array(
            'column-1' => '<a href="#">' . (string)rand() . '</a>',
            'column-2' => '<img src="' . $iconPath . '" /> ' . (string)rand(),
        );
    }

    $list = new pm_View_List_Simple($this->view, $this->_request);
    $list->setData($data);
    $list->setColumns(array(
        'column-1' => array(
            'title' => 'Random with link',
            'noEscape' => true,
        ),
        'column-2' => array(
            'title' => 'Random with image',
            'noEscape' => true,
        ),
    ));
    // Take into account listDataAction corresponds to the URL /list-data/
    $list->setDataUrl(array('action' => 'list-data'));

    return $list;
}
```

and the latter on

```
public function listAction()
{
    $list = $this->_getListRandom();

    // List object for pm_View_Helper_RenderList
    $this->view->list = $list;
}
```

And I'm totally stuck on one issue: How to disable sorting for particular column ? I was looking for some solution over internet, but I haven't found any. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, sorting parameters are hardcoded in pm_View_List_Simple class.